# Why do my objects have different heights even when I gave them the same?

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```css
.title-card {
  display: block;
  height: 56.25vw;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-overlay .title {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.title-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  height: 56.25vw;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56.25vw;
}

.background-overlay {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-card">
  <div class="background-overlay">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3RMr6m1B-qM/maxresdefault.jpg" class="background">
  </div>
  <div class="title-overlay">
    <div class="title">
      Hello there, and welcome! This site is still unfinished but feel free to look around.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, all of my heights are set to 56.25vw. However, in the actual page, the title-card's and background's heights are 698.52px while the title-overlay's height is 698.18px. According to my calculator, 698.52px should be the correct height. So why is my title-overlay a bit shorter?

Comment: there are half pixels :_) ?

Comment: Heights work differently for different display types. For tables, `height` works much like `min-height` if there's enough room to grow.

Comment: okay then how do I make it so that they have the same height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because display:table; calculates height differently from block elements.

I don't know exactly why it does but my guess is that it does not allow half pixels somewhere in the calculation.

For example: set the height of everything to 300px and all elements will have 300px height but if you set all heights to 300.75px the block elements will be 300.75px and the table element will be 300px.

To fix your problem I would recommend just stop using tables.

If you want to center everything the same way you can use a inline-block element with 56.25vw in line-height and then having a inline-block element inside it with line-height: normal;

Example below:

```css
.title-card {
  display: block;
  height: 56.25vw;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-overlay .title {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.title-overlay .title-container {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:56.25vw;
}

.title-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 56.25vw;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56.25vw;
}

.background-overlay {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-card">
  <div class="background-overlay">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3RMr6m1B-qM/maxresdefault.jpg" class="background">
  </div>
  <div class="title-overlay">
  <div class="title-container">
    <div class="title">
      Hello there, and welcome! This site is still unfinished but feel free to look around.
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.title-card {
    display: block;
    height: 56.25vw;
    width: 100%;
}

.title-overlay .title {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);

    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 2em;

    display: table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    padding: 1em;
}

.title-overlay {
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;

    display: table;

    width: 70%;
    height: 60vw;
}

.please-work {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 56.25vw;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;

    width: 100%;
    height: 56.25vw;
}

.background-overlay {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-card">
        <div class="background-overlay">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3RMr6m1B-qM/maxresdefault.jpg" class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="please-work">
            <div class="title-overlay">
                <div class="title">
                    Hello there, and welcome! This site is still unfinished but feel free to look around.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Well, I've found myself a disgusting "fix." I'm not really satisfied with it but if it works, then it works, I guess.